# I need to print/return multiple elements from tuple in Python

Tags: python

I have a list of strings and tuples. The tuples look like this (number, element):

```
s = ["element1", (3, "element2"), (2, "element3")]
```

I need the tuple to be printed like this:

```
element1
element2
element2
element2
element3
element3
```

That is, I need number*element prints. The best I came up with was this:

```
s = ["element1", (3, "element2"), (2, "element3")]

def bb (x):
    for n in x:
        if isinstance (n, str):
           print (n)
        if isinstance (n, tuple):
            print (n[1])
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's a one-liner:

```
s = ["element1", (3, "element2"), (2, "element3")]
result = sum(([x] if type(x) != tuple else x[0]*[x[1]] for x in s), [])
```

Or extending your existing code:

```
def bb(x):
    for n in x:
        if isinstance(n, str):
            print(n)
        elif isinstance(n, tuple):
            count, value = n
            for i in range(count):
                print(value)
```

If you want to return these values, you might want to use a generator:

```
def bb_gen(x):
    for n in x:
        if isinstance(n, str):
            yield n
        elif isinstance(n, tuple):
            count, value = n
            for i in range(count):
                yield value

for value in bb_gen(s):
    print value
```

Comment: @Lattyware: Not in all cases. What if you had a `namedtuple` in there (being used as a class)?

Comment: Would it be possible to do something from what I already have? I am working on some uni assignments from a friend and I try to learn at their pace and do stuff they have to do, since it probably has a pedagogical purpose...

Comment: @Eric Then don't use a ``namedtuple`` if you don't want a tuple.

Answer (score 2):

Ideally, change your input so you get `[(1, "element1,"), ...]`, but if that isn't possible:

```
import types
import itertools

s = ["element1", (3, "element2"), (2, "element3")]

print(list(itertools.chain.from_iterable((e, ) if isinstance(e, str) else itertools.repeat(e[1], e[0]) for e in s)))
```

Gives us:

```
['element1', 'element2', 'element2', 'element2', 'element3', 'element3']
```

What we are doing here is taking your elements and turning them into tuples if strings (so they don't get iterated over into characters), and using `itertools.repeat()` to create an iterator that repeats them the number of times given if they are tuples. We then use `itertools.chain.from_iterable()` to flatten this collection of collections into a single iterator, which we then turn into a list.

Note in 2.x, you want `isinstance(e, basestring)`.

Edit: Alternatively:

```
args = ((e, 1) if isinstance(e, str) else (e[1], e[0]) for e in s)
itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.starmap(itertools.repeat, args))
```

It's the same thing, but maybe a little neater in my opinion.

Comment: What's the difference between `types.StringType` and `basestring`?

Comment: @Eric: `basestring` is the parent class of both `str` and `unicode` (`types.StringType` and `types.UnicodeType`).

Comment: In 2.x, you want to use `isinstance(e, basestring)` perhaps? And `isinstance(e, str)` would work just fine too.

Comment: Indeed, I was wrong, I thought that ``types.StringType`` was what ``basestring`` is, edited. I don't use 2.x enough to remember such things clearly. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Just checked: `types.StringType is str`